# Can I use ASP.NET 3.5 at a server with just .NET 2.0?

Tags: .net, asp.net

If I pre-compile all `ASPX/ASCX` files using Publish and send all `System.*` dlls that exists in `.NET 3.5`. will work?

Comment: How do you expect to do that...?

Comment: Just Copy System.Core.dll, System.Web.Extensions.DLL, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a test and worked, but I needed to modify web.config, removing the compilers element that uses csc.exe 3.5. Since I send all files pre-compiled I had no problems

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer here depends on what your project's dependencies are.  ASP.NET 3.5 doesn't really exist - for all intensive purposes it's ASP.NET 2.0 with some new extensions that Visual Studio helps you integrate.  It's not a standalone framework.

If you're not using LINQ or AJAX I bet your site deploys just fine.  If you are using LINQ/AJAX you might find yourself doing a lot of manual assembly entries in your Web.config.

Comment: However, what you are losing is compile-time verification of your code. Why can you not just recompile under 2.0???

Comment: @Cat - I don't think he's losing compile-time verification.  He wants to precompile his site.  He'll get all benefits except for the performance optimization he'd get by allowing for on-demand compilation, which would only be a benefit if the processor architecture he's deploying to is different from his dev box...

Comment: What I mean is that it will accept 3.5 functionality, which may not be available in the destination.

Answer (score 1):

As said earlier here, it depends!
Some stuff will probably work, but some won't.

If there's a .NET 2.0 assembly in the GAC and you place a 3.5 assembly in the bin folder, your application will use the GAC assembly (2.0) by default. Therefore you can never be sure if your application will run correct.

You can install the 3.5 framework without a server reboot, so you don't have to be afraid of any downtime, perhaps 1 iisreset to make everything work, but I haven't had to do that in the past.

Answer (score -1):

No it won't work. You will have to install the proper .NET framework on the server itself.

You really expected different answer?

Comment: I don't believe this is correct.  This is not like deploying a 2.0 website to a 1.1 box.  This is more like deploying a 2.0 website with a third party reference to another machine that doesn't have the 3rd party product installed...  if you include the DLL you need, it should still run...